# nginx advanced rewrite

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I'm trying to create a rewrite in nginx that i can't seem to get working quite right...

What i'm trying to do:

rewrite:

`bleh.com/productPage/productname/?action=yes&id=12`

to:

`bleh.com/productPage/index.php?product=productname&action=yes&id=12`

The closest i've gotten so far is:

```
location / {
rewrite ^/productPage/(.*)/(.*)$ /productPage/index.php?$1 last;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
fastcgi_index ... (and the rest of the working fastcgi config)
```

However that i'm only hitting 404's..

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
location /productPage/ {
  rewrite ^/productPage/(.*)/$ /productPage/index.php?product=$1 index.php last;
}
```

note: [the rewrite directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) matches the regex on [the $uri variable](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#.24uri) which does NOT include the arguments, the arguments will be attached to the rewriten url automatically unless you end your replacement path with `?`